# How do I write polars dataframe to external database?

Tags: python, sqlite, rust, python-polars

I have big polars dataframe that I want to write into external database (sqlite for example)
How can I do it?

In pandas, you have to_sql() function, but I couldn't find any equivalent in polars

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For **`polars>=0.16.10`** you can use `df.write_database()` [method](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.16.10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DataFrame.write_database` method.

Answer (score 2):

Polars doesn't provide a utility for inserting data to a database.

Your options, that I can think of, are:

1. `to_pandas().to_sql(...)`
2. DIY

   a.  Generate insert statements from `df.rows()` like [this](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/io/postgres.html)

   b.  Apparently sqlite doesn't do bulk inserts but for postgres you can use a combination of `io`, `write_csv`, and [`copy_from`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=copy#cursor.copy_to) which will be much faster than using insert statements.
3. Save parquet files and either use them directly or use something like duckdb to access them as though they were a traditional db